# Use the value of a string variable as the 'index' of an existing object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using JavaScript.

I have

```
var myobj = {
    "one": {
        "name": "paul",
        "no"  : "A123"
    },
    "two": {
        "name": "mike",
        "no"  : "B456"
    },
    "three": {
        "name": "andy",
        "no"  : "C789"
    },
};
```

I have another object `newitem` that I want to insert

```
var newIndex = "four";
var newItem = {
    "name": "leo",
    "no"  : "D987"
};
```

How do I insert `newItem` into `myobj` using `newIndex` as the 'index'?

By the way, `newIndex` is not generated by me so I cannot just say `myobj.four = newItem;` `myobj.newIndex = newItem` doesn't work since it uses the word 'newIndex' as the index instead of its value.

Any insights?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the bracket notation property accessor:

```
myobj[newIndex] = newItem;
```

It is also useful when you want to define a property whose name is not a valid Identifier, e.g.:

```
obj["1foo"] = "bar"; // `obj.1for` will cause a SyntaxError
obj["a b"] = "bar"; // `obj.a b` will cause a SyntaxError
```

Note that you can even use an expression with this property accessor, e.g.:

```
obj[someFunc()] = "foo";
```

It will evaluate the expression between the brackets, and it will convert the result to string, because JavaScript doesn't have *true* hash tables, property names must be of type String.

More info:

- [Member Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Member_Operators)

Comment: Note that in the latest edition of the standard on which JavaScript is based, it's not necessary to use bracket notation when referring to properties named by keywords or reserved words: `obj.for = 'me'` is permitted by ECMAScript 5th edition.  (A few other contexts, such as property names in object literals, also have been loosened to permit keywords.)  This change has been implemented in Firefox, for one, for a few years now, if you want to play with it.

Comment: @Jeff, yeah, forgot to  mention it, in ES5 an `IdentifierName` can be used with the `.` property accessor. I'll make a better example...